# Why are there two locations for deep links in Push Notifications?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

There is two locations for specifiying deep links within Marketing Cloud Push notification messages.

One in the Message "Open Behavior" and the other in the Journey Push Activity under "Advanced Options".

Can someone explain what the differences are? and what happens if both have different values?